Is the Staging Ground relevant to sites other than Stack Overflow?
Recently, Stack Overflow has been abuzz with the newly implemented Staging Ground.  I don't use Stack Overflow often, so I'm not sure if this is going to be implemented in some form at the sites I frequent.
Question: Is the Staging Ground relevant to sites other than Stack Overflow?
I'm a bit worried that this feature will suddenly appear at other sites, and we won't have any experience using it.

how could you ever have experience of something before it appears? There's a first time for everything.

Technically it should be relevant. It's somewhat modelled after existing things like the Sandbox for proposed Questions on Worldbuilding.SE and the Sandbox for Proposed Challenges on CodeGolf.SE. I don't if/when it is scheduled to replace them (and be rolled out network-wide), though. I suspect it won't be forcefully rolled out but each site would have to opt-in.

I think there were deeply informal discussions that oine of the previous initiatives - the ask questions wizard might be a solution to the off topic posts problem here.

Yes, it is relevant.
From the initial announcement here on Meta Stack Exchange:

That said, if the test is successful and these features graduate on Stack Overflow, we hope to also be able to release them on other sites around the Stack Exchange network that would like to take advantage of these new workflows for helping new question askers onboard more successfully. (It is not yet decided whether these would be enabled or disabled by default for sites on the network, though individual sites would be able to change from the default either way.)

Based on past experience, if this really reaches that stage, it will be disabled by default, and each site will have to ask in its per-site meta for it to be enabled, then staff will enable it.
This would let each site discuss it first and prepare.
